# Как добавить схему метро на карту?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

[image]

Как добавить схему метро в приложение, как в официальной версии карт от google?

Answer (score 2):

Добавить `Polyline` на карту

```
// Instantiates a new Polyline object and adds points to define a rectangle
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0))
        .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.0))  // North of the previous point, but at the same longitude
        .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.2))  // Same latitude, and 30km to the west
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.2))  // Same longitude, and 16km to the south
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0)); // Closes the polyline.

// Get back the mutable Polyline
Polyline polyline = myMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

Подробнее [тут](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes?hl=ru)

Comment: Ну это самый примитивный способ. Я думал может существует какой-нибудь встроенный метод